# A misunderstanding or a bug in LAPACK's solver for generalized eigenvalue problems?

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, generalized-eigenvector

I have two general real matrices $A$,$B$ defined as follows,
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
-s I_3 & A_0    & 0      & 0 \\
A_0^T  & -s I_3 & 0      & 0 \\
0      & A_1    & -s I_3 & A_0 \\
A_1^T  & 0      & A_0^T  & -s I_3
\end{bmatrix},
B=\begin{bmatrix}
0   & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
0   & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
I_3 & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
0   & I_3& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $A_0,A_1 \in R^{3\times3}$ are general matrices, $s$ is a real scalar, and $I_3 \in R^{3\times3}$ is the identity matrix. I would like to solve the eigenvalue problem $AX= B X D$ numerically, where $X$ is the eigenvector matrix and $D$ is the eigenvalue matrix. I only want the right (not left) eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Consider the following as a concrete example,
where
$$
A_0=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &   & \\
   & 2 & \\
   &   & 3
\end{bmatrix},
A_1=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
s=1,
$$
From my application, I know there exists at least one eigenvalue $d_1$ and one eigenvector $x_1$, which are
$$
x_1=\left(0.625543,0,0,0.625543, 0, 0, 0, -0.417029, 0, 0, -0.208514, 0\right),
d_1=0,
$$
because $ A x_1 -d_1 B x_1 = \textbf{0},\left\|x_1\right\|=1$. However, no matter which software I used, I couldn't get the correct eigenvalues, even for $d_1$. The software I have tried are Matlab, Eigen(c++ library) and LAPACK.

1. The eigenvalues from Matlab are infinity.
2. The right eigenvalues from Eigen and LAPACK are represented by $d_i=\alpha_i / \beta_i$, where $\alpha_i$ is a complex number and $\beta_i$ is a real number. The output $\beta_i$ is zero for all eigenvalues. In other words, all right eigenvalues are infinity.

I'm not sure which part is wrong. Is it that the software cannot compute a correct eigenvalue or that $d_1$ cannot be considered as an eigenvalue?

Edit 1: changed title as suggested by Carl. Also, cross-posted this question to the suggested forum [A misunderstanding or a bug in LAPACK's solver for generalized eigenvalue problems?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36053/a-misunderstanding-or-a-bug-in-lapacks-solver-for-generalized-eigenvalue-proble).

Comment: Thank you very much for this very interesting example. I can partially confirm the output from MATLAB which as far as I know will call LAPACK's dggev. I get 9 infinities and 3 NaN (presumably from indefinite eigenvalues). I find that the specific $x$ you list in the null space of A (at least to the digits given). Therefore your conclusion that $(0,x)$ is a generalized eigenpair for $(A,B)$ is correct. I don't have the time right now, but try to obtain condition numbers for the eigenvalues using DGGEVX from LAPACK.

Comment: I recommend that you have this question migrated to our sister [forum](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) which is a much better fit. Also consider changing the title to "A misunderstanding or a bug in LAPACK's solver for generalized eigenvalue problems?"

Comment: If you crosspost yourself, then make sure to have the two questions reference each other.

Comment: @CarlChristian The reciprocal condition numbers of the eigenvalues returned by DGGEVX's RCONDE are (-1,2.874e-31,1.659e-31,9.579e-32,2.142e-31,3.095e-16,4.152e-16,9.787e-16,1.141e-15,-1,6.714e-16,-1). Also, there are two zero singular values for $A$.

Comment: I think that the condition numbers settle the issue. I will remember this example. In general, it may be worth while to check the numerical rank of $A$ and $B$ if there is an cause for concern.